# How does one correctly pass on ofstream object?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, ofstream

I am writing code to have input student and grade objects, sort them, calculate an average gpa, and output them to a file. My current problem is that the output of my student objects are given after I sort them and print them, but the code does not seem to leave the loop once I do that. I have a print function in which I am passing an ofstream. From debugging, I know that the out ofstream object reads everything, but then it seems to freeze, and not output anything else into it. Can somebody tell me if I passed by reference incorrectly, or if I need to do something else? The error where the compiler didn't keep going through is marked in the code.

Sorry, so for more information, below is a snip it of what is run

[output code in text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9zW5.png)

Notice how "got through it" is only displayed once. I know that it's not an issue opening the file and outputting, because it actually did output the right stuff. Also, for correction, the compiler actually compiles everything fine. It is at runtime where the terminal stalls and nothing more is output.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Grade.h"
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

const double A_NUM = 4.0, B_NUM = 3.0, C_NUM = 2.0, D_NUM = 1.0, E_NUM = 0.0, B_PLUSSNUM = 3.4, C_PLUSSNUM = 2.4, D_PLUSSNUM = 1.4;
const double A_MINUSNUM = 3.7, B_MINUSNUM = 2.7, C_MINUSNUM = 1.7, D_MINUSNUM = 0.7;
const int FIRST_INDEX= 0;
const int START_NUM = 0;
const int LESS_ONE = 1, ABOVE_ONE = 1;
const int START_GRADE = 0;

void calcgrades(vector<Grade>& grades)//function that calculates gpa based on letter grades
{
    const string A = "A", A_MINUS = "A-", B_PLUSS = "B+", B = "B", B_MINUS = "B-", C_PLUSS = "C+", C = "C", C_MINUS = "C-", D_PLUSS = "D+", D = "D", D_MINUS = "D-", E = "E";
    int counter = START_NUM;//used to keep track of current student and current total grade
    double current_grade = START_NUM;

    for(int i = 0; i < grades.size();i++)
    {

        //while loop to get the student's current total grade if the next student id is different than the first one.
        while(i < grades.size()-LESS_ONE && grades[i].getid() == grades[i+ABOVE_ONE].getid())
        {
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == A)
            {
                current_grade == A_NUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == B)
            {
                current_grade == B_NUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == C)
            {
                current_grade == C_NUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == D)
            {
                current_grade == D_NUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == E)
            {
                current_grade == E_NUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == B_PLUSS)
            {
                current_grade == B_PLUSSNUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == C_PLUSS)
            {
                current_grade == C_PLUSSNUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == D_PLUSS)
            {
                current_grade == D_PLUSSNUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == A_MINUS)
            {
                current_grade == A_MINUSNUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == B_MINUS)
            {
                current_grade = B_MINUSNUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == C_MINUS)
            {
                current_grade = C_MINUSNUM + current_grade;
            }
            if (grades[i].getgrade() == D_MINUS)
            {
                current_grade = D_MINUSNUM + current_grade;
            }

        }


        if (grades[i+ABOVE_ONE].getid() !=  grades[i].getid() || i == grades.size()-LESS_ONE)
        {

            //computes the average if the currentid is not equal to the nextid
            double avggpa = current_grade/counter;

            grades[i].newgpa(avggpa);
            counter = START_NUM;//resets counter for a new student to get his gpa
        }

        counter++;
    }
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string student_file, grades_file, idnum, name, address, pnum, course, gletter;

    //creates student and grade objects from respective classes
    vector<Student> students;
    vector<Grade> grades;


    student_file = argv[1];

    //reads in information from file to import into student objects
    ifstream sfile;

    sfile.open(student_file);




    while(getline(sfile, idnum))//gets the student information from student file
    {
        getline(sfile, name);
        getline(sfile, address);
        getline(sfile, pnum);

        //creates student objects to import info. into, and inserts into students vector
        Student s(idnum, name, address, pnum);
        students.push_back(s);

    }

    sfile.close();

    //opens information from the grade file
    grades_file = argv[2];

    //reads from file to import into grades objects
    ifstream gfile;

    gfile.open(grades_file);

    //gets the grade information from the grades file
    while(getline(gfile, course))
    {
        getline(gfile, idnum);
        getline(gfile, gletter);

        //creates grade objects to import info, and inserts into grades vector
        Grade g(course, idnum, gletter, START_GRADE);
        grades.push_back(g);
    }

    gfile.close();

    //reads the query file
    string query_file;
    query_file = argv[3];

    ifstream qfile;

    qfile.open(query_file);

    //reads from query file
    //creates vector to store each student number
    vector<string> query_nums;
    string incheck;

    while(getline(qfile, incheck))
    {
        query_nums.push_back(incheck); 
    }

    qfile.close();

    //sorts the information for the students
    sort(students.begin(), students.end());


    //sorts the information for the grades
    sort(grades.begin(), grades.end());

    ofstream outtxt;

    string out_file = argv[4];

    outtxt.open(out_file);

    //outputs the student information, sorted now.
    for(int i = 0; i < students.size();i++)
    {
        students[i].print(outtxt);

        outtxt << "got through it";
    }

    //compiler did not get past here!
outtxt << "We're here!";

    //outputs the grades with student id's, now sorted
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++)
    {
        grades[i].print(outtxt);
        outtxt << "\n\n" << "some output!";
    }


    //calculates the average gpa for every student
    calcgrades(grades);



    for(int i = 0; i < query_nums.size(); i++)//goes through each query number to check first
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < students.size(); j++)//after, goes through each student object
        {
            if (query_nums[i] == students[j].getid())
            {
                //finds the gpa in the grades class that matches the student id
                for (int k = 0; k < grades.size(); k++)
                {
                    if (grades[k].getid() == query_nums[i])//
                    {
                        //outputs the resulting id, avg gpa, and name of matching students
                        outtxt << grades[i].getid() << "\tthere is nothinghere" << grades[i].getgpa() << "\t" << students[i].getname();

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    outtxt.close();

return 0;

}
```

student class with print function

```
class Student
{

private:
    string idnum;
    string name;
    string address;
    string pnum;

public:

    //defines constructor
    Student(string idnum,string name,string address,string pnum);


    //prints each student info
    void print(ofstream& out);

    string getname();

    string getid();

    bool operator < (Student s) const {
    return idnum < s.idnum;
  }


};
```

student cpp file

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Student constructor, used to make student objects
    Student::Student(string id,string nm,string add,string pnumber)
{
    idnum = id;
    name = nm;
    address = add;
    pnum = pnumber;
}

    void Student::print(ofstream& out)
    {
        out << name << endl << idnum << endl << pnum << endl << address << endl;
    }

    string Student::getname()
    {
        //returns the student name
        return name;
    }


    string Student::getid()
    {
        return idnum;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please add the compiler error

Answer (score 0):

In answer your question regarding how to correctly pass an ofstream object, you are passing it correctly.

So why doesn't it work? From what is available to observe from your code, it should work just fine. I would suggest debugging the output file name in these lines of code:

```
ofstream outtxt;

string out_file = argv[4];

outtxt.open(out_file);
```

Verify that the open function succeeded by checking the ios::fail flag after calling the open function.

Try something like this after opening:

```
if (ios::fail)
    cout << "fail";
```

I hope this helps.

Edited: There may be other problems, but the calcgrades() function has an access violation on the last for loop iteration, after the while loop, at this if statement:

```
    if (grades[i+ABOVE_ONE].getid() !=  grades[i].getid() || i == grades.size()-LESS_ONE)
```

Comment: I know that it's not an issue opening the file and outputting, because it actually did output the right stuff. See additional pic above ^

Comment: @RickGiovanini What does the debugger show on the second loop, after stepping over "students[i].print(outtxt);"?

Comment: Sorry, I know this might be off topic, but I don't really have a debugger. I have to use ubuntu and sublime text along with the terminal for a class, and I don't know how to align that easily with visual studio (argv and char in the main, etc). So, that's probably one of my biggest problems as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @RickGiovanini, Also try adding this line after each write (just for debugging) and see if anymore lines show up in the output file: outtxt.flush();

Comment: More success, but not quite there! Thanks for the help so far. The code added 1 more "got through it" when I put the flush after the "got through it" text in the loop. I put the flush on the outside of the loop as well, but it didn't get to "we're here!"

Comment: @RickGiovanini The flush is after "we're here!" ?

Comment: the flush is before, "we're here!" Oh, yea. Those were the only students that it should have got through, so it should be done with the loop, but it doesn't want to exit for some reason.

Comment: @RickGiovanini I think it can be concluded that the students loop is fine. Place a debug write inside each loop and inner loop along with a flush call. I am guessing you don't have access to the console output? If so, place a cout << "some text" inside each loop after each statement. Those nested loops can get nasty. Your problem might be there.

Comment: I agree that it very well could be the nested loops, but wouldn't it still output the text, "We're here!" before it even got to those loops?

Comment: @RickGiovanini Take a look at my edit in my main answer. That will solve at least one of the problems.